# Adding an extension to multiple classes/interfaces on Dart

Tags: dart

I've run into a situation where I would like to have an extension method that will work on any class that implements at least two interfaces.

Example:

```
class Named {
   String get name;
}

class Gender {
   String get gender;
}

extension ExampleExtension on Named, Gender {
   String get info => "$name is a $gender"
}
```

However, I cannot seem to have an extension on more than on class. Is this possible in dart?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible.

You can only add extensions to *types*, and (`Named` *and* `Gender`) is not *a* type.

What you are asking for is "intersection types", which Dart does not have.

You need to introduce an actual type which extends both `Named` and `Gender` in order to have something to attach the extension to.